# What is the correct way to reshape images after raveling?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

At the moment I'm trying to `np.ravel()` my images so I can use `np.append()` freely, instead of using `np.vstack()` which many people here say it's not very fast given the loading/unloading things in memory and I worry it might slow my code down.

My idea was to just flatten the images, append them all and then use `np.reshape(appended_images, [512,512,3,-1])` to create the tensor. The tensor is created all right, but upon checkup, the images aren't getting displayed, probably because one of these operations is not working the way I think it should be working.

Checking the final array `im_stacked[:,:,:,0]` with matplotlib returns a blank image, with a warning of values out of range. Upon inspection of only one channel of the image `im_stacked[:,:,0,0]` I'm faced with this:

[image: Many copies of the same image inside the image in a 3x3 matrix]

This is just the image repeated over and over. Where is my mistake? Why is there some swapping occurring? Reshaping a single raveled image works fine.

Edit: Minimal code added

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Image Loading, please use a 512x512x3 image
path = "./path/to/image.png"
im = cv.imread(path)

#Flattening the image
im_raveled = np.ravel(im)

#Starting with an empty array
im_stacked = np.array([])

#For the sake of simplicity this code is just repeated three times
im_stacked = np.append(im_stacked, im_raveled)
im_stacked = np.append(im_stacked, im_raveled)
im_stacked = np.append(im_stacked, im_raveled)

#Using a 515x512x3 image, reshaping the stacked array
im_reshaped = np.reshape(im_stacked, [512,512,3,-1])

#Plotting the images after reshaping
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)

#Plot only the first channel of the first image
plt.imshow(im_reshaped[:,:,0,0])
plt.subplot(1,2,2)

#Plot all channels of the first image
plt.imshow(im_reshaped[:,:,:,0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: "many people here say it's not very fast given the loading/unloading things in memory and I worry it might slow my code down" -- You should implement things in a simple and readable way, and if *then* you find it too slow, find a way to speed it up. Don't try to optimize things that might not be bottlenecks at all. Note that even the most experienced programmers are often wrong when intuitively guessing at relative speeds of different bits of code.

Comment: `np.append` is worse than `np.vstack`.  it's no better for speed, and leads users into more errors.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've added a minimal program to show the problem at hand. I usually don't try to optimize things beforehand but the last time I did something close to this, I did it in a dirty way which didnt seem ideal (starting a 2d array with garbage and then deleting the first index after filling the rest of the tensor).

Comment: @hpaulj the problem I faced with `np.vstack` was that I couldnt start with an empty array and then stack my subsequent layers because it asked me for the dimensions beforehand. Is there some way to start it with an empty array?

Comment: Try adding `order='F'` to your `np.reshape` call.

Comment: Or maybe this needs to be `np.reshape(im_stacked, [-1,512,512,3])`. It depends on the data order you get when you load your images. Pay attention to the order of the data in memory, and all will be resolved.

Comment: That's because you don't really understand dimensions.  Plus repeated vstack, or `np.append` is a bad idea.  Stick with list append if you need to work in a loop.

Comment: @CrisLuengo adding 'F' to the reshape makes the the first plot even more jumbled, the second shows something but I can't tell it apart. I've tried all the possible combinations in the ravel and reshape. Using F in the ravel and F in the reshape makes the channel appear, but the the final image is still garbled.

Comment: @hpaulj It seemed straightforward enough but I'm seeing that it isn't. Any resources on that topic you'd recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Make a sample 3d array:

```
In [25]: image = np.random.randint(0,256,(512,512,3))
```

The best way:

```
In [26]: alist = []
In [27]: for i in range(5):
    ...:     alist.append(image)
    ...:
```

It's easy to make an array from such list:

```
In [28]: np.array(alist).shape
Out[28]: (5, 512, 512, 3)
```

If you must join them on a new last dimension, use `np.stack`:

```
In [29]: np.stack(alist,-1).shape
Out[29]: (512, 512, 3, 5)
```

`np.stack`, `np.vstack`, and even `np.append` are all covers for `np.concatenate`.  I hate `np.append`, since it leads too many naive users up the wrong path.  It is **not** an list append clone.

If you **must** use repeated concatenates do something like:

```
In [30]: arr = np.zeros((0,512,512,3),image.dtype)

In [31]: arr = np.concatenate([arr,image], axis=0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-31-1fc945fd1c90>", line 1, in <module>
    arr = np.concatenate([arr,image], axis=0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 4 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 3 dimension(s)
```

oops, even with experience I have troubles getting that started.

```
In [32]: arr = np.concatenate([arr,image[None,...]], axis=0)
In [33]: arr.shape
Out[33]: (1, 512, 512, 3)
In [34]: arr = np.concatenate([arr,image[None,...]], axis=0)
In [35]: arr.shape
Out[35]: (2, 512, 512, 3)
```

Repeated `concatenate` is slow.  `concatenate` takes a whole list of arrays, and should be used as such. Don't try to replicate list code in lists!

List append is easy because there's an obvious "empty" list, and you can efficiently add references to it.  Arrays don't have an equivalent "empty" array.  Dimensions matter, right from the start.  I had to start with a (0,512,512,3) shape.  If you don't know the needed dimensions, then don't take this approach.

---

As for your title question, this might work:

```
im_reshaped = np.reshape(im_stacked, [-1,512,512,3])
```

With the repeated `np.append`, you joined the ravelled arrays end to end, `[(786432,),(786432,),(786432,),...]`.  Effectively the new dimension is a leading one, not a trailing one.  It's a crude way of performing the list append and array build that I started with.